# Display the name of the subjects and their marks after pushing to new array

Tags: arrays, typescript

HERE IS MY CODE,

```js
let subjects: string[] = ['Mathemetics-70', 'Science-67', 'English-88', 'Geography-62', 'ComputerSc-55'];

function uppercase(subject: string) {
  return subject.toUpperCase();
}

let subjects_upppercase = subjects
  .map(uppercase)
  .toString()
  .match(/\d+/g)
  .map(function (numbers) {
    return parseInt(numbers);
  })
  .filter(function (number) {
    if (number > 65) {
      return true;
    }
  })
  .map(function (newarray) {
    return newarray;
  });
console.log(subjects_upppercase);
```

I have an array of numbers [70,67,88]
now I want to print names of subjects corresponding to the numbers inside an array.
can someone help with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution (I didnt quite get what your requirements where but here you go)

```
const subjects: string[] = ["Mathemetics-70","Science-67","English-88","Geography-62","ComputerSc-55"];

const pairs = subjects.map(subject => {
    const subjectNumber = subject.match( /\d+/);
    if (!subjectNumber) return undefined;
    return [parseInt(subjectNumber[0]), subject.toUpperCase()]
}).filter(Boolean)


const obj = Object.fromEntries(pairs); 
console.log(obj); // this will be { number: subject }

// and if you want to print only your numbers use 

const toPrint = [70,67,88];
for (let numberToPrint of toPrint){
    console.log(obj[numberToPrint]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my solution, the code is:

```
let subjects: string[] = ['Mathemetics-70', 'Science-67', 'English-88', 'Geography-62', 'ComputerSc-55'];

const str = subjects.join("\n");

const arr = [70, 67, 88].map((num) => {
    return str.match(new RegExp("(\\w+\-)" + num))[0];
});

console.log(arr);
// ['Mathemetics-70', 'Science-67', 'English-88']
```